# Hibernate-4 show SQL code that is generated

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, log4j

I created a Maven project in my eclipse IDE and trying to write simple hibernate program. But I am not able to see the final query that is generated by hibernate which also includes the bind parameters.

I also followed the post mentioned here : [Hibernate show real SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536829/hibernate-show-real-sql) , but it did not help.

I have below configurations:

In my `hibernate.cfg.xml` file I have:

```
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
```

I also placed `log4j.properties` file with its contents:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO, hb
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST=info
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=warn
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql=debug
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cache=info
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=debug
log4j.logger.net.sf.hibernate.type=debug

log4j.appender.hb=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.hb.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.hb.layout.ConversionPattern=HibernateLog --> %d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.hb.Threshold=TRACE
```

Both `hibernate.cfg.xml` and `log4j.properties` are placed at path :

```
MyProject/src/main/java/log4j.properties
```

But still when I run a small program I am not able to see the bind parameters that are added by hibernate, I am just seeing below results:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        this_.ID as ID1_0_0_,
        this_.NAME as NAME2_0_0_
    from
        MY_TABLE this_
```

I am using `Hibernate-4.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `SLF4J` dependency in `pom.xml` has fixed my issue:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
log4j.logger.net.sf.hibernate.type=debug
```

to:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace
```

And you should get the bind parameter.

Comment: @user2065083 I have changed my answer. please try again.

Comment: I already have that setting in my log4j.properties file --> log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE, now I tried removing only the line `log4j.logger.net.sf.hibernate.type=debug`, still no change in output

Comment: Thanks Jens for your support, I don't have slf4j in my pom.xml dependency list so the log4j.properties file is not picked.

Answer (score 0):

The **`log4j.properties`** file must be located in the following directory:

```
MyProject/src/main/resources/log4j.properties
```

Thus, log4j will find this file in the classpath without any additional configuration.

---

See also [*Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout*](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) in the [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) webpage.

<sup>You may want to see the next question: **[Logging server logs to one file and SQL logs to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25415103/logging-server-logs-to-one-file-and-sql-logs-to-another)**.</sup>

Comment: Thanks Paul for the answer, I have placed it in resources path, but still there is no change in the output, this way is not working for me.